# Java - Determine if a ZipInputStream contains a Entry

Tags: java, zip, fileinputstream

I'm currently trying to create a method that merges several `ZipFile`s into one big. Therefore I created a method that takes a output file and a list of `InputStream`s.

These `InputStream`s are later transformed into `ZipInputStream`s. That works fine!

But I have trouble when a file has already been added to the archive. At this point I need to override the entry already added (`InputStream`s with a higher index (lower in the list) should override the files from streams with a lower index). I also know how to do that: I just do not add the entry if a archive that would need to override it.
But the problem is how could I check if a entry is contained in a `ZipInputStream` so I can skip the addition of the entry for the current stream?

My code so far:

```
    public static void makeNewZipFromInputStreamList(File outputFile,
            ArrayList<InputStream> inputStreamList,
            ArrayList<String> includeList, ArrayList<String> excludeList)
            throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        final int sizeOfLists[] = new int[] { inputStreamList.size(),
                includeList.size(), excludeList.size() };

        if ((sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[1])
                || (sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[2])
                || (sizeOfLists[1] != sizeOfLists[2]))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The ArrayLists do not have the same size ("
                            + sizeOfLists[0] + ", " + sizeOfLists[1] + ", "
                            + sizeOfLists[2] + ")");

        final ZipOutputStream zipOutputFile = new ZipOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        final int size = sizeOfLists[0];
        InputStream inputStreamTempArray[] = inputStreamList
                .toArray(new InputStream[size]);
        String includeArray[] = includeList.toArray(new String[size]);
        String excludeArray[] = excludeList.toArray(new String[size]);

        int i, j;
        ZipInputStream stream, streamTmp;
        ZipInputStream inputStreamArray[] = new ZipInputStream[size];
        String include, exclude, fileName;
        ZipEntry entry;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            inputStreamArray[i] = new ZipInputStream(inputStreamTempArray[i]);

            if (includeArray[i] == null) {
                includeArray[i] = "";
            }

            if (excludeArray[i] == null) {
                excludeArray[i] = "";
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            while ((entry = inputStreamArray[i].getNextEntry()) != null) {
                fileName = entry.getName();

                for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                    // Check if the entry exists in the following archives (Then skip this entry)
                }

                if (fileName.matches(includeArray[i]) || !fileName.matches(excludeArray[i])) {
                    zipOutputFile.putNextEntry(entry);

                    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                        copyStream(inputStreamArray[i], zipOutputFile, false, false);
                    }
                }
            }

            inputStreamArray[i].close();
        }

        zipOutputFile.close();
    }
```

copyStream:

```
    private static boolean copyStream(final InputStream is,
            final OutputStream os, boolean closeInputStream,
            boolean closeOutputStream) {
        try {
            final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            if (closeInputStream) {
                is.close();
            }

            if (closeOutputStream) {
                os.close();
            }

            return true;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I had the idea to just append the entries the other way round meaning starting from the end of the list and if a entry is already put it is just going to skip.

When I'm doing this I get a really weird error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 1506 but got 1507 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at io.brainstone.github.installer.FileUtils.makeNewZipFromInputStreamList(FileUtils.java:304)
    at io.brainstone.github.installer.Main.startInstalling(Main.java:224)
    at io.brainstone.github.installer.Window$3$1.run(Window.java:183)
```

This is my current code:

```
    public static void makeNewZipFromInputStreamList(File outputFile,
            ArrayList<InputStream> inputStreamList,
            ArrayList<String> includeList, ArrayList<String> excludeList)
            throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        final int sizeOfLists[] = new int[] { inputStreamList.size(),
                includeList.size(), excludeList.size() };

        if ((sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[1])
                || (sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[2])
                || (sizeOfLists[1] != sizeOfLists[2]))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The ArrayLists do not have the same size ("
                            + sizeOfLists[0] + ", " + sizeOfLists[1] + ", "
                            + sizeOfLists[2] + ")");

        final ZipOutputStream zipOutputFile = new ZipOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        final int size = sizeOfLists[0];
        final InputStream inputStreamTempArray[] = inputStreamList
                .toArray(new InputStream[size]);
        final String includeArray[] = includeList.toArray(new String[size]);
        final String excludeArray[] = excludeList.toArray(new String[size]);
        final ZipInputStream inputStreamArray[] = new ZipInputStream[size];

        HashMap<String, Object[]> tmp;

        int i, j;
        String fileName;
        ZipEntry entry;

        for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(i);

            inputStreamArray[i] = new ZipInputStream(inputStreamTempArray[i]);

            if (includeArray[i] == null) {
                includeArray[i] = "";
            }

            if (excludeArray[i] == null) {
                excludeArray[i] = "";
            }

            while ((entry = inputStreamArray[i].getNextEntry()) != null) {
                fileName = entry.getName();

                if (fileName.matches(includeArray[i])
                        || !fileName.matches(excludeArray[i])) {
                    // Here is where I would check if a entry is already put.
                    // Probably just by catching the exception thrown in this
                    // case
                    zipOutputFile.putNextEntry(entry);

                    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                        copyStream(inputStreamArray[i], zipOutputFile, false,
                                false);
                    }
                }
            }

            inputStreamArray[i].close();
        }

        zipOutputFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is iterating backwards through the ArrayLists.

```
    public static void makeNewZipFromInputStreamList(File outputFile,
            ArrayList<InputStream> inputStreamList,
            ArrayList<String> includeList, ArrayList<String> excludeList)
            throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        final int sizeOfLists[] = new int[] { inputStreamList.size(),
                includeList.size(), excludeList.size() };

        if ((sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[1])
                || (sizeOfLists[0] != sizeOfLists[2])
                || (sizeOfLists[1] != sizeOfLists[2]))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The ArrayLists do not have the same size ("
                            + sizeOfLists[0] + ", " + sizeOfLists[1] + ", "
                            + sizeOfLists[2] + ")");

        final ZipOutputStream zipOutputFile = new ZipOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        final int size = sizeOfLists[0];
        final InputStream inputStreamTempArray[] = inputStreamList
                .toArray(new InputStream[size]);
        final String includeArray[] = includeList.toArray(new String[size]);
        final String excludeArray[] = excludeList.toArray(new String[size]);
        final ZipInputStream inputStreamArray[] = new ZipInputStream[size];

        HashMap<String, Object[]> tmp;

        int i, j;
        String fileName;
        ZipEntry entry;

        for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            inputStreamArray[i] = new ZipInputStream(inputStreamTempArray[i]);

            if (includeArray[i] == null) {
                includeArray[i] = "";
            }

            if (excludeArray[i] == null) {
                excludeArray[i] = "";
            }

            while ((entry = inputStreamArray[i].getNextEntry()) != null) {
                fileName = entry.getName();

                if (fileName.matches(includeArray[i])
                        || !fileName.matches(excludeArray[i])) {
                    try {
                        zipOutputFile.putNextEntry(entry);

                        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                            copyStream(inputStreamArray[i], zipOutputFile,
                                    false, false);
                        }
                    } catch (ZipException ex) {
                        if (!ex.getMessage()
                                .matches("duplicate entry: .*\\..*")) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                    "Unexpected " + ex.getClass() + " (\""
                                            + ex.getMessage()
                                            + "\")\n(only duplicate entry execptions are expected!)",
                                    ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            inputStreamArray[i].close();
        }

        zipOutputFile.close();
    }
```

But thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold a map from `fileName` to `entry`.
2. Iterate over all entries in all input streams and put the entries in the map, mapped by file name. Last entry will always override previous. When you finish you have only all highest-indexed entries per file name.
3. Iterate over the map's entries and put them to `zipOutputFile`.

   ```
   // (1) here all entries will be stored, overriding low-indexed with high-indexed
   final Map<String, ZipEntry> fileNameToZipEntry = new HashMap<String, ZipEntry>();

   // (2) Iterate over all entries and store in map, overriding low-indexed
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

       while ((entry = inputStreamArray[i].getNextEntry()) != null) {
           fileName = entry.getName();
           fileNameToZipEntry.put(fileName, entry);
       }

       inputStreamArray[i].close();
   }

   // (3) Iterating the map that holds only the entries required for zipOutputFile
   int j = 0;
   for ( Set<Map.Entry<String, ZipEntry>> mapEntry : fileNameToZipEntry.entrySet() ) {

       if (fileName.matches(includeArray[j]) || !fileName.matches(excludeArray[j])) {

           zipOutputFile.putNextEntry(entry);

           if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
               copyStream(inputStreamArray[j], zipOutputFile, false, false);
           }
       }
       j++;
   }
   ```

Comment: The idea is very good! But it can't be realized in this way because you forgot that the ZipInputStream is at the end after you iterated through it the first time. You also forgot that the variable `i` can't be used in the second for loop.

Comment: @YannickSchinko well you got the idea then :). I tried to make it as succinct as possible for clarity reasons.

Comment: @YannickSchinko no wait a minute, the second iteration **is not over the `ZipInputStream`, rather on the map**.

Comment: @YannickSchinko and also the `i` variable **isn't used in the second iteration**.

Comment: @YannickSchinko oh sorry, you're right about the `i` variable. I'll fix it.

Comment: You have to know that I don't really have understood how everything with Streams works. I have tried arround for over 30 minutes and have had several ideas how I could use this technique. But since the `ZipInputStream`s are completly read and there is no way to reset them I have no idea what I could try next! Meaning getting a way to reuse these streams or just have a peak at the entries list would solve my problems.

Comment: that still doesn't fix it. Because I still cannot use a close stream that is either closed or at its end (`copyStream(inputStreamArray[j], zipOutputFile, false, false);`)! By the way: There are more than one file in each archive which makes your iteration of `j` pointless!

Comment: @YannickSchinko you should only iterate the input streams once. You store the entries in a map and close all input streams as all relevant entries have been read. Then you iterate the map which holds the read entries and write them the output stream.

Comment: @YannickSchinko could you please post `copyStream(...)`?

Comment: You still suggest copying a stream that is already closed (`copyStream(...)` in step 3). And just adding entries does not fill them with data!

Comment: I had another, by far simpler, idea. But it still doesn't work. Can you help me? (I updated the start post)